# How do I do the Minkowski sum of two sets?

Tags: vector, sets

I have 2 sets, $X$ and $Y$. How do I find the Minkowski sum of these sets?

Comment: according to wikipedia: `Join @@ Outer[Plus, X, Y, 1]`? Not sure if one should `Union` at the end, is this what you need?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I don't know when the word was added, but I think minkowski sums can be used by using [RegionDilation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287922/how-to-create-a-random-zonogon/287931#287931) as described in the 3D solution.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is with `Tuples` and `Total`.

```
A = {1, 2, 3};
B = {a, b, c};

MinkowskiSum[lis__] := Total[Tuples[{lis}], {2}]

MinkowskiSum[A, B]
```

> ```
> {a+1, b+1, c+1, a+2, b+2, c+2, a+3, b+3, c+3}
> ```

```
A1 = {1, 2};
A2 = {a, b};
A3 = {x, y};

MinkowskiSum[A1, A2, A3]
```

> ```
> {a+x+1, a+y+1, b+x+1, b+y+1, a+x+2, a+y+2, b+x+2, b+y+2}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

For example

```
x = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}};
y = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}};

Union @@ Outer[Plus, x, y, 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -2}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}}
> ```

---

You can use [`CirclePlus (⊕)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePlus.html) (entered as \[CirclePlus] or <kbd>Esc</kbd>c+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) to define your Minkowski sum:

```
CirclePlus[x__] := Flatten[Union @@ Outer[Plus, x, 1], Length@{x} - 2]

x⊕y
```

> ```
> {{0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -2}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}}
> ```

```
{{1,2}}⊕{{a,b}}⊕{{c,d}}
```

> ```
> {{1 + a + c, 2 + b + d}}
> ```

Comment: How come it doesn't work with this problem? :(
https://projecteuler.net/problem=228
I made two sets:
s[3]={{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 0}, {1/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}};
s[4]={{1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {-(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}, {-(1/Sqrt[2]), -(1/Sqrt[2])}, {1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[2])}}
But when I did Graphics[{Green, Polygon[s[3]\[CirclePlus]s[4]]}], I got something super crazy. Though now that I look at the overall shape, I feel like the outermost 6 points could result in the same shape as in the problem, but for some reason it's filled in a really strange way.

Comment: @Solarmew Use `Point` instead of `Polygon` to see that it does work and use `Line` to see why your `Polygon` doesn't have the expected shape.

Comment: I see. That's what I suspected. Is there a way to actually get the needed filled shape? Though even at that point, I'm not entirely sure how I'm gonna extract the number of sides from it %\ ...

Comment: @Solarmew you might be looking for [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html) and [Region Properties and Measures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricPropertiesAndMeasures.html).