# How to create a random zonogon?

Tags: graphics, regions, random, polygons

A [zonogon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonogon#:%7E:text=A%20regular%20polygon%20is%20a,the%20rhombi%2C%20and%20the%20parallelograms.) is a polygon that is convex and is made only out of pairs of parallel sides with the same length. Any regular polygon with an even number of sides is an example of a zonogon.

When I use: `Graphics[RandomPolygon[{"StarShaped", 10}]]`, I get something like this: [image: random Star-Shaped Decagon]

When I use: `Graphics[RandomPolygon[{"Convex",6}]]`, I get something like this: [image: random convex hexagon]

And for regular polygons, we can do something different with: `Graphics[RegularPolygon[{randomPositiveReal, randomAngle}, randomInteger]]`.

But unfortunately there is no option for zonogons. The code: `Graphics[RandomPolygon[{"Zonogon",6}]]` gives an error.

I found this gives a random hexagon that is a zonogon before a random rotation:

```
height=500;
width=500;
X6={};AppendTo[X6,RandomReal[{0,width}]];AppendTo[X6,RandomReal[{0,height}]];
X3={};AppendTo[X3,RandomReal[{X6[[1]],width}]];AppendTo[X3,X6[[2]]];
X1={};AppendTo[X1,RandomReal[{X6[[1]],X3[[1]]}]];AppendTo[X1,RandomReal[{0,X3[[2]]}]];
X2={};AppendTo[X2,RandomReal[{X1[[1]],X3[[1]]}]];AppendTo[X2,X1[[2]]];
X4={};X4=X3+X6-X1;
X5={};X5=X3+X6-X2;
ListLinePlot[{X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X1},Axes->False]
```

Which gives something like this:

[image: random hexagon that is also a zonogon]

When I look at more examples of zonogons [here](https://pershmail.substack.com/p/shape-of-the-week-zonogon), I noticed that I believe zonogons can be made by 'stretching' parallel sides of a regular polygon.

**How can I do this to make a random zonogon in Mathematica?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get some shapes with `AffineTransform` and `Rotate`. Define:

```
zonogon[n_]:=
Rotate[GeometricTransformation[Rotate[RegularPolygon[n],RandomReal[2Pi]],
AffineTransform[RandomReal[1,{2,2}]]],RandomReal[2Pi]]
```

Then generate a few:

```
Table[Graphics[zonogon[RandomChoice[Range[4, 14, 2]]]], 10]
```

[image]

Comment: When I check it, it seems like it never collapses to having fewer sides than it is supposed to. Also, I learned what an affine transformation is. I didn't know the word for that concept before today. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

We can using `Minkowski Sum` ([`RegionDilation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDilation.html)) of any `Line`'s from the fixed point `p`.

- For 3D.

```
p = {0, 0, 0};
n = 10;
lines = Table[Line[{p, p + RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 3]}], n];
polyhedron = Fold[RegionDilation, lines];
HighlightMesh[polyhedron, {Style[1, White], Style[2, Darker@Cyan]}, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image]

- For 2D.

```
p = {0, 0};
n = 4;
lines = Table[Line[{p, p + RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 2]}], n];
poly = Fold[RegionDilation, lines];
Graphics[{FaceForm[Darker@Cyan], EdgeForm[Thick], poly, Thick, 
  Orange, lines /. Line -> Arrow, White, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
  Point[p]}]
```

[image]

- For 2D,we demonstrate the process of the `Region Dilation`.After that, we want to subdivide the region into some `Parallelogram`s.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
p = {0, 0};
n = 9;
dirs = RandomPoint[Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {-(π/2), π/2}], n];
lines = Line[{p, p + #}] & /@ dirs;
polys = FoldList[RegionDilation, lines];
parts = Most@MapThread[RegionDifference, {Rest@polys, Most@polys}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, White}], FaceForm@RandomColor[], #} & /@ 
  parts]
```

[image]

- One way to subdivede the zonogon into `Parallelogram`s.

```
SeedRandom[1];
p = {0, 0};
n = 11;
dirs = RandomPoint[Circle[{0, 0}, 1], n];
lines = Line[{p, p + #}] & /@ dirs;
polys = FoldList[RegionDilation, lines];
parts = Most@MapThread[RegionDifference, {Rest@polys, Most@polys}];
pts = MapThread[
    Complement, {Rest[First /@ polys], Most[First /@ polys]}][[2 ;; 
     n - 2]];
Animate[Graphics[{MapIndexed[{ColorData[97][First@#2], #1} &, parts], 
   Arrowheads[.025], White, 
   Take[MapThread[
     Arrow /@ Thread[{#1 - Threaded@#2, #1}] &, {pts, 
      dirs[[3 ;; n - 1]]}], i]}], {i, 1, n - 3, 1}, AnimationRate -> 1]
```

[image]

- By lifting the 2D data to 3D, we can found that subdivede the zonogon into `Parallelogram`s is not unique.

```
SeedRandom[1];
p = {0, 0};
n = 11;
dirs = RandomPoint[Circle[{0, 0}, 1], n];
 pic = 
 Graphics3D[
  Fold[RegionDilation, 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0} + #}] & /@ (PadRight[#, 3] & /@ dirs)], 
  ViewPoint -> Top, 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]; SeedRandom[]; 
pics = 
 Table[Graphics3D[
   Fold[RegionDilation, 
    Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0} + #}] & /@ 
     MapThread[Append, {dirs, RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]}]], 
   ViewPoint -> Top, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"], 
  4]; 
GraphicsRow[{pic, pics} // Flatten]
```

[image]

**Edit**

- To subdivide the 2D case to varies several `Parallelogram`s is still not so easy. Here we only provided one possible way. I think if we can find the way to change the hexagons in the figure, we will get many subdivides.

```
k = 7;
es = RandomReal[{0, 1}, k]*
   SortBy[RandomPoint[Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, π}], k], 
    VectorAngle[{1, 0}, #] &];
level[j_] := 
  MapThread[
   Polygon[Join[#1, Reverse@#2]] &, {Partition[#, 2, 1] &@
     FoldList[Plus, Take[es, -j]], 
    Partition[#, 2, 1] &@
     Prepend[FoldList[Plus, Take[es, -j + 1]], {0, 0}]}];
Graphics[
 Table[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][j]], EdgeForm[{White, Thick}], 
   level[j]}, {j, 1, k}]]
```

[image]

- Change the direction of vectors, we can draw a picture similar with https://pershmail.substack.com/p/shape-of-the-week-zonogon

```
Clear[k, es, level];
k = 13;
es = AngleVector /@ Table[-(π/(2 k)) + j*π/k, {j, 1, k}];
es = CirclePoints[{1, π + π/(2 k)}, 2 k];
level[j_] := 
  MapThread[
   Polygon[Join[#1, Reverse@#2]] &, {Partition[#, 2, 1] &@
     FoldList[Plus, Take[es, -j]], 
    Partition[#, 2, 1] &@
     Prepend[FoldList[Plus, Take[es, -j + 1]], {0, 0}]}];
Graphics[
 Table[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][j]], EdgeForm[{White, Thick}], 
   level[j]}, {j, 1, k}]]
```

[image]

- Transpose the data to get the same pattern of colors.

```
lear[k, es, level];
k = 13;
es = CirclePoints[{1, π + π/(2 k)}, 2 k];
level[j_] := 
  MapThread[
   Polygon[Join[#1, Reverse@#2]] &, {Partition[#, 2, 1] &@
     FoldList[Plus, Take[es, -j]], 
    Partition[#, 2, 1] &@
     Prepend[FoldList[Plus, Take[es, -j + 1]], {0, 0}]}];
polys = Flatten[Table[level[j], {j, 1, k}], {{2}, {1}}];
Graphics[
 Table[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][i]], EdgeForm[{Thick, White}], 
   polys[[i]]}, {i, 1, k - 1}]]
```

[image]

### a mathematical conjecture

It seems that every `"StarShaped"` can be extend to a unique `"Convex"` by extend `Parallelogram`.(the code need to be improved)
[image]

And every `"StarShaped"` which construct by `Parallelogram`s can be extend to a unique `"Zonogon"`.

[image]

Comment: What does $n$ mean for the 3D case?

Comment: @TegLouis  `n` is the numbers of the lines from the point `p`.

Comment: I don't have a  proof, but think a zonogon is a projection of a cylinder with zonogon end caps. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4707792/finding-the-dimensions-of-a-box-cuboid-given-a-hexagon-filled-in-to-look-like) is an example for hexagons that are also zonogons being a projection of a cuboid. I don't know if this holds for breaking the 2D case into parallelograms.

Comment: Also, your solution is the coolest looking one. Zonogons are so cool and important, but I was stunned to only find 96 papers about them on Google Scholar, and a large percentage were just exposé's of repetitive information.

Comment: How can I download anamination file?

Comment: @cvgmt The question: [How to creatively create a random belt polygon or belt polyhedron?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288408/how-to-creatively-create-a-random-belt-polygon-or-belt-polyhedron) is a generalization of this question.

Answer (score 9):

You can start with a regular 2n polygon that has 2 sides parallel to the x axis. Then stretch the polygon along the x axis. Afterwards, you rotate the polygon so that the next side is parallel to the x axis and stretch again. After you did this n times, you have your zonogon.

```
n = 3;
pts = CirclePoints[2 n];
Do[
  add = RandomReal[1];
  pts[[;; n]] = (# + {add, 0}) & /@ pts[[;; n]];
  pts[[n + 1 ;;]] =  (# - {add, 0}) & /@ pts[[n + 1 ;;]];
  pts = RotateRight[pts];
  , {n}];
AppendTo[pts, pts[[1]]];
Graphics[Line[pts], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I think your solution is the best so far that demonstrates mathematically what goes under the hood. It is very concise.

Answer (score 6):

A much cheaper way is by just creating directions and line pieces and assembling (over the much more expansive Minkowski sum/RegionDilation), and much more random than the stretched regular polygons:

```
ClearAll[CreateRandomZonogon]
CreateRandomZonogon[sides_?EvenQ, lendist : {min_, max_}] := 
 Module[{m, angles, dirs, lengths},
  m = sides/2;
  angles = RandomReal[{0, 1}, m];
  angles /= Total[angles]/(Pi);
  angles = Join[angles, angles];
  dirs = Accumulate[angles];
  dirs += RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];
  lengths = RandomReal[lendist, m];
  lengths = Join[lengths, lengths];
  Polygon[Accumulate[MapThread[AngleVector[{#1, #2}] &, {lengths, dirs}]]]
  ]
CreateRandomZonogon[8, {0.5, 1}] // Graphics
```

here the first argument is the number of sides (should be even). And then the second specification is the range of lengths for the sides, which i set to 0.5 to 1, but can be anything (positive).

Comment: Also, yours is probably the best one so far for generalizing and abstracting to solve related mathematics problems. And it is extremely readable and customizable.

Comment: The question: [How to creatively create a random belt polygon or belt polyhedron?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288408/how-to-creatively-create-a-random-belt-polygon-or-belt-polyhedron) is a generalization of this question. It used your solution. I am not 100% sure it always makes a belt polygon though.